# IIS 7 Configuration problem?

Tags: iis-7, timeout, wcf-data-services

I have a client application which query an ADO.NET Data Service hosted by a IIS 7.
My solution work fine if my client application run on the same machine that the IIS 7.
When I run the client application on a second machine, I get in trouble : after some request I start to have some timeout.

I have two Web Methods in my Data Service :

- GetNextImage
- SetProcessOrderDone

I Made a console application that call only the GetNextImage Method and it work fine, even on a remote machine.
I modify this console application in order to query the GetNextImage and de SetProcessOrderDone method and i start to have timeout when working on a remote machine.
I commented all my code in the Web methods but still the same...
I use the windows event log for tracing the method and the execution is OK and return well.
Why I have Timeout error ? And why only when I work with a second computer ? I think it's a IIS configuration problem but I can't figure it out...

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, it's not a IIS configuration problem but the way I call the Web Method. I use http request and I forget to call the Close() method.